# Como passar os dados de uma linha do DataTable para um Dialog no PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, java-ee

Tenho uma DataTable na qual tenho vários dados e um botão selecionar. Ao clicar no botão selecionar chamo um Dialog com mais alguns campos. Gostaria de ao clicar no botão selecionar ele pegasse os dados do Objeto e preenchesse os campos desse Dialog.

Esse é o método que gera o Dialog:

```
@ManagedBean(name="dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class ListaProcedimentosBean {
    public void abrirDialogo() {
            Map<String, Object> opcoes = new HashMap<>();
            opcoes.put("modal", true);
            opcoes.put("resizable", false);
            opcoes.put("contentHeight", 670);
            opcoes.put("contentWidth", 870);
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("procedimentosPesquisaCompleta", opcoes, null);
        }
}
```

E aqui está o botão selecionar:

```
<p:column headerText="Opções">
                <p:commandButton value="Selecionar" icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{dtBasicView.abrirDialogo}" process="@this">
                </p:commandButton>
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Boas, para isso o melhor mesmo é seguir o exemplo do showcase da primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml
Se calhar efetuar o "abrirDialogo" no xhtml em ves de no bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percebo que estás usando o componente *Dialog Framework* do PrimeFaces.
O terceiro parâmetro do método `openDialog(pagina, opcoes, params)` serve para ser passado os dados (parâmetros) para o diálogo, o ruim desse parâmetro do método é que só é aceito um `HashMap` de `List<String>`.

Por isso, uma abordagem que pode ser feita é passar o código do item para o método `openDialog()` e no `ManagedBean` da página do diálogo recuperar esse código que está como parâmetro, e após isso carregar os dados restantes e exibi-los na página do diálogo.

Por exemplo:

**Passar o objeto selecionado para o `ManagedBean`**

```
<p:column headerText="Opções">
    <p:commandButton value="Selecionar" icon="ui-icon-search" 
                     action="#{dtBasicView.abrirDialogo}" process="@this">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dtBasicView.objetoSelecionado}" value="#{objeto}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

**Pegar o objeto selecionado e abrir o diálogo**

```
public void abrirDialogo() {
  Map<String, Object> optionsDialog = new HashMap<>();
  optionsDialog.put("modal", true);
  optionsDialog.put("resizable", false);
  optionsDialog.put("contentHeight", 670);
  optionsDialog.put("contentWidth", 870);

  Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("meuParametro", Arrays.asList(""+objetoSelecionado.getCodigo()));           

  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
      .openDialog("procedimentosPesquisaCompleta", optionsDialog, params);
}
```

**Pegar o parâmetro passado para o diálogo**

Pode ser no construtor do `ManagedBean` que controla a página aberta no diálogo.

```
String paramResposta = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRequest()).getParameter("meuParametro");

    if(paramResposta != null && !paramResposta.isEmpty()){
        int codigo = Integer.parseInt(paramResposta);
        Objeto = dao.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
    }
```

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito também. Como você acabou de colocar ficaria até mais simples, pois todos os dados restantes poderiam ser obtidos do banco a partir desse código recebido como parâmetro. Ou seja, sem a necessidade de realizar o *parse* para JSON e vice-versa.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta para essa situação.